# How to convert nested arrays with strings to numbers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I don't know how deep my array is. It could be:

```
let array = ["1000", "5000", "3000"];
```

Or:

```
let array = [ ["4000", "2000", "1000"], ["6000", "7000", "3000"] ];
```

I would like to convert them in to real numbers. The preferred handler is lodash. But I appreciate every solution.

What I tried was:

```
let array = array.map(Number);
```

But that covered one dimensional arrays.

Comment: Please provide additional information for your down votes, thanks!

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see how to ask and you will see we need EFFORT and CODE to help you: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]_

Comment: I added my approach.

Comment: Here is an exact duplicate I found using lodash as one answer. You could have found that too :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333918/js-deep-map-function

Comment: Thanks, @mplungjan. One could doubt the exactness ;) I always do research before I post a question.

Comment: You would have had less or no downvotes had you told us that and perhaps shared the research :) It is a lodash nested method - sounded very exactly like what you were asking for

Comment: @mplungian He's not seeking debugging help, so the part you quote does not apply. The problem statement is also perfectly clear.

Comment: @torazaburo - the quote fits. It did not even HAVE the code for "why isn't this code working" but now it does. As a member for 5 years you know how this site works and the lack of example code was why it was voted down. Hence my explanation using the nearest "close" explanation available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method with a recursive approach for the nested array.

```
function conv(arr) {
  // iterate over the array
  return arr.map(function(v) {
    // if the element is an array call the function recursively
    // or parse the number and treat NaN as 0
    return Array.isArray(v) ? conv(v) : Number(v) || 0;
  })
}
```

```js
const array = [
  ["4000", "2000", "1000", ""],
  ["6000", "7000", "3000"]
];
const array1 = ["1000", "5000", "3000"];

function conv(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(v) {
    return Array.isArray(v) ? conv(v) : Number(v) || 0;
  })
}

console.log(conv(array));
console.log(conv(array1));
```

---

With ES6 [arrow syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) :

```
let conv = arr => arr.map(v => Array.isArray(v) ? conv(v) : Number(v) || 0)
```

```js
const array = [
  ["4000", "2000", "1000", ""],
  ["6000", "7000", "3000"]
];
const array1 = ["1000", "5000", "3000"];

let conv = arr => arr.map(v => Array.isArray(v) ? conv(v) : Number(v) || 0)

console.log(conv(array));
console.log(conv(array1));
```

Comment: any particular reason behind using a 'const' key instead of any other?

Comment: @BekimBacaj, the array won't change.

Comment: @PranavCBalan we know what const declaration is, we just think that it's a misuse - nobody will change your array. :)

Answer (score 1):

A more general solution would be a version of `map` which takes any function and works on either arrays OR scalars:

```js
const maybeMap = fn => x => Array.isArray(x) ? x.map(maybeMap(fn)) : fn(x);

const numberify = maybeMap(Number);

const array = ["1000", ["2000", "3000"], "4000"];
console.log(numberify(array));
```