# How to trim the object inside object using typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I tried to trim in an object inside objects but it's not working. anyone give the example code trim in an object inside the object.

**Example**

```
const data = {tgg:" egg ",ggg:{dfgf:" tyt "}, ff:[{tyuyy:" sd f "}]}
```

how to trim this object in all scenario

**Excepted Output**

```
 {tgg:"egg",ggg:{dfgf:"tyt"}, ff:[{tyuyy:"sd f"}]}
```

Only remove first and back space

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Do you mean trim the white space of the string values?

Comment: You can look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333918/js-deep-map-function and use one of the functions posted there to do `deepMap(data, x => x.trim())`

Comment: Added Excepted output can you check

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of object. If the current value is an object, recursively call the function on the value. If the current value is a string, trim it. This will work for any level of nesting.

```js
const data = {
  tgg: " egg ",
  ggg: {
    dfgf: " tyt "
  },
  ff: [{
    tyuyy: " sd f "
  }]
}

function customTrim(o) {
  for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(o)) {
    if (Object(v) === v)
      customTrim(v)
    else if (typeof v === 'string')
      o[k] = v.trim();
  }
  return o;
}

console.log(customTrim(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = {
  tgg: " egg ",
  ggg: {
    dfgf: " tyt "
  },
  ff: [{
    tyuyy: " sdf "
  }]
};

const _data = JSON.stringify(data).replace(/"\s+|\s+"/g, '"');
console.log(JSON.parse(_data));
```